# Is it possible to use same stopwatch multiple times

Tags: c#

I want to calculate the time my code runs and compare it to a different code. so I'm using a `stopwatch` for it and it works well. But I wonder if it is possible to use one stopwatch for more than one measure?

```
Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();

sw1.Start();

//Long running code

sw1.Stop();

long run1 = sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds;

Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
sw2.Start();
        
//Long running code
        
sw2.Stop();

long run2 = sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Yes. But there is no real savings in this.  Keep your code clean and create a new one where you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use the .Reset() method to reset the stopwatch.
Or the .Restart() to both reset and restart the stopwatch

```
Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();
sw1.Start();

//Long running code

sw1.Stop();

long run1 = sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds;
sw1.Reset(); // <---- Reset  or Restart can be used 
sw1.Start();
//Long running code
sw1.Stop();

long run2 = sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```